# Simple jQuery Toggle In Wordpress

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress, toggle

I am trying to create a simple hide/show toggle with jquery in a custom wordpress page template.

This is my html that I have in the custom page template:

```
<div id="questionFaq">
    <b>This is a question?</b>
</div>
<div class="answerFaq">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</p>
</div>
```

This is my script in a folder called "js":

```
jQuery("#questionFaq").on("click", function () {
    var state = $(this).data('state');
    state = !state;
    if (state) {
        $(".answerFaq").addClass("show");
    } else {
        $(".answerFaq").removeClass("show");
    }
    $(this).data('state', state);
});
```

I then enqueue the script in functions.php like this:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_script' );
function add_my_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'togglescript', 
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/togglescript.js', 
        array('jquery') 
    );
}
```

When I load the page the script loads in the source however when I go to the actual page, the script isn't actually working?

Answer (score 0):

```
        jQuery(document).on("click","#questionFaq", function () {
            var state = $(this).data('state');
            state = !state;
            if (state) {
                $(".answerFaq").addClass("show");
            } else {
                $(".answerFaq").removeClass("show");
            }
            $(this).data('state', state);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `.data` attribute and then toggling a class attribute, you can do the following:

- Check if the answer is visible
- And then do a `.show()` or `.hide()`

It's a simple solution.

**HTML Markup**

Questions and answers should use the [`<dl>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-dl-element) along with the `<dt>` and `<dd>` elements per W3C, as Q&As are name-value groups.

> Name-value groups may be terms and definitions, metadata topics and values, questions and answers, or any other groups of name-value data.

I added the microdata for you too.

**The Code**

```js
(function($, window, document){
    "use strict";

    var init = function() {
        $('.faq-question').on("click", faqHandler);
    }

    var faqHandler = function() {
        var $answer = $(this).next();

        if ($answer.is(':visible')){
            $answer.hide();
        } else {
            $answer.show();
        }

        return false;
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
        init();
    });

}(jQuery, window, document));
```

```css
.faq-question {
    padding:  10px;
    background-color: #ddd;
    margin: 30px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<dl class="faq-container">

  <dt class="faq-question" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Question">What happens when you click this question?</dt >

  <dd class="faq-answer" style="display: none;" itemscope itemtype="http://scheme.org/Answer">the answer appears to delight you.</dd >

</dl>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hellofromtonya/ov937ca7/)

**Improving**

I'd advise that you had an icon also to indicate direction or a clicking action.  It will improve the user experience.

Second, it's best to add a version to the script enqueue. Why?  WordPress appends the version to the script's URL.  When you make changes, you uptick the version.  That will change the URL, which tells the browser to download the new version.

Otherwise, if someone previously visited the site before the changes, their browser will use the cached version.  They will not see the changes, i.e. assuming they haven't cleared their browser's cache.